# Understanding multiple inheritence and super based on some code from David Beazly

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

I watched a [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=js_0wjzuMfc) from David Beazly in which he implemeneted type checking using multiple or more specifically diamond inheritence. I thought that his approach looked really cool but it also confused me and I simply can't figure out how it is working. Here is the code im talking about:

```
class Contract:
    @classmethod
    def check(cls, value):
        pass


class Integer(Contract):
    @classmethod
    def check(cls, value):
        assert isinstance(value, int), 'Expected int'
        super().check(value)


class Positive(Contract):
    @classmethod
    def check(cls, value):
        assert value > 0, 'Must be > 0'
        super().check(value)


class PositiveInteger(Positive, Integer):
    pass
```

And here it is in action:

```
>>> PositiveInteger.check(-3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in check
AssertionError: Must be > 0
>>> PositiveInteger.check(4.88)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in check
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in check
AssertionError: Expected int
```

My Questions are:

1. Why is the definition of a base class Contract with a method check needed to make this work?
2. I have a basic understanding of what super does. I know it lets us avoid calling the base class explicitly and somehow deals with multiple inheritence. But what does it do in this example exactly?

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: @NickT: I am aware of this thread and I did read it but it didn't help me understanding this problem

Comment: I think the idea is that somewhere in the MRO there should/must be a method so you put it in the base class - even if it doesn't do anything or just raises a NotImplemented exception.

Comment: Take a look at the practical Advice section of [Python's super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Comment: @wwii: I think I did express myself unclear. Could you have a look at my comment at Artyer's answer?

Comment: You have asked two questions in this question - one deals with a different solution which you haven't provided.  You also seem to have modified your question with a comment to an answer.  Maybe you should regroup, think about your problem and ask specific questions (one at a time) that help you get to an understanding.

Comment: @wwii: It wasn't my intetnion to modify my original question. This is probably due to my poor english. But thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go through it line by line like a debugger.

```
PositiveInteger.check(x)

# Method resolution order:
# PositiveInteger, Positive, Integer, Contract (from Positive), Contract (from Integer)

# Look through MRO for .check() method. Found in Positive.

assert x > 0
super().check(value)

# super() checks for next .check() method in MRO. Found in Integer

assert isinstance(x, int)
super().check(value)

# super() checks for next .check() method in MRO. Found in Contract

pass
```

To easily find the method resolution order, use [`inspect.getmro()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmro).

If you had explicitly used the base class, after `Positive`, the base class is `Contract`, so `Integer` would never be called.

You need to define `.check()` in `Contract` as when you call the last `super()`, if `Contract` didn't have the `.check()` method, it would have raised an `AttributeError`, as `super()` wouldn't have been able to find it.